# create chat application

Tags: xmpp, osgi, chat, bundle

I will develop a chat application using OSGI so t have doubt between 3 propositions:

using an existing chat server but i have the problem of security of channel
  developing a chat server 
  using a bundle for chat

can you help me on my choice

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague and you only present 2 propositions, both of which are more related to a server than a chat application (as your title implies).  You might want to clarify your question or risk getting it closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing server if your only concern is security.

Security is built into the XMPP protocol by means of SASL, TLS and SSL.